# Как правильно работать с кириллицей в url?

Tags: php, url, кириллица

Решил использовать кириллицу в `url`. Ссылки на картинки и сами `url` вида `site.com/картинка.jpg` и `site.com/news/главная-новость-дня` я вывожу из бд обычным способом.

Нужно ли текст кодировать, декодировать как написано [тут](http://www.design-sites.ru/utility/url-encoding.php)?

Текст отображается как надо в ссылках, правда, одно но, при копировании адреса изображения и последующей вставки куда-нибудь, почему-то вставляется в закодированном виде, но, при переходе по ней обращается обратно в нормальную кириллицу.

Со ссылками на страницы сайта, такого нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Большинство браузеров умеют автоматически кодировать адреса если это нужно. А современные браузеры умеют еще и декодировать URL в адресной строке для показа пользователю (при этом запросы на сервер идут всегда с кодированным URL). Но на это лучше не полагаться - ведь разные браузеры могут использовать разные кодировки. И если эта кодировка не совпадает с той, которую использует сервер при декодировании URL - все "поломается".

Поэтому лучше кодировать URL на стороне сервера, где вы точно знаете ту кодировку, в которой потом будете декодировать.

Comment: т.е. мне строку просто взять в `/news/'.urldecode($news->url).'` к примеру

Comment: Только не `urldecode`, а `urlencode`. Да, так и надо сделать.

Comment: да, точно) спасибо

Comment: у меня в `url` кроме кириллицы и `-` нет ничего

Comment: Извиняюсь, про `htmlspecialchars` я ерунду сказал. У `urlencode` на выходе хитрых символов не бывает.

Comment: все равно при копировании ссылка изображения, получаю следующее `%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%BE%`

Comment: Но так и должно быть.

Answer (score -2):

Я использую `urldecode urlencode` для `get post` запросов, для остальных случаев думаю не нужно, то есть когда передаю данные в ссылке, потому что, даже один пробел может попортить много нерв.